# Get value of xsi:type with javascript

Tags: javascript, json, soap

I am working with AngularJS. Getting a response from SOAP.

having problem reading the value of xsi:type

```
[{"attributes":{"xsi:type":"TicketNote"}]
```

How can i get the value of xsi:type using just Javascript or AngularJS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var obj =[{"attributes":{"xsi:type":"TicketNote"}}];
console.log(obj[0].attributes["xsi:type"]);
```

Comment: I should have mentioned that was an object not an array, but changing it to an array and using this solves my problem